# Can anyone suggest a Java or Scala DOS/terminal-based UI framework?

Tags: java, windows, scala, frameworks

I'm looking for some framework to build an interface like Turbo C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a Text User Interface peer for the AWT: http://www.bmsi.com/tuipeer/

Other TUI libraries include [JavaTUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javatui/) and [CHARVA](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html)

CHARVA is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 7):

Six years later, you can consider (for Scala 2.12+) [**`Tenchi2xh/Scurses`**](https://github.com/Tenchi2xh/Scurses)

Scurses and Onions are frameworks for drawing nice things in your terminal using simple, elegant Scala. Scurses provides a low-level drawing and event handling API while Onions provides a high-level UI API with useful widgets.

[image: screen shot 2015-11-12 at 10 58 51]

Comment: That looks awesome but it doesnt seem to be supported anymore ? No more commits and not available on Maven ?

Comment: @Wonay THis days, this is implemented in Go (https://appliedgo.net/tui/, for instance https://github.com/gizak/termui#termui)

Comment: ah that's too bad !

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [JavaCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) library.